# Login Page with REST API done using Retrofit & sharedPreferences to store required credentials

Tags: flutter, rest, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I wanted to implement login page with functionality and login should be validated by a rest Api with post method and integration should be done with Retrofit and After login user should land on home page also  SharedPrefrences to store the required credencials. so that when user is login login screen should not showing Again and again. how to start implementing all this?

I tried this but not understanding what next:

**Login Page:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:task1/HomePage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
 
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Trails',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MainPage()
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Trails"),
    
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(               
                      child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png')),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0,right: 
           15.0,top:0,bottom: 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(                     
                      labelText: 'Username',
                      hintText: 'Enter your username'),
                       validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter your username';
                  }
                   return null;
                 },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Password', hintText: 'Enter secure password'),
                       validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.trim().isEmpty) {
                            return 'Enter the password';
                          } else
                            return null;
                        },                  
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Forgot Password',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 125,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 175, 80, 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child:ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  HomePage()),
                     );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Login'),
            ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**APIClient.dart :**

```
import 'package:retrofit/http.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'APIClient.dart';
 
@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://api.*****.****/authentication")

abstract class APIClient {

  factory APIClient(Dio dio) = _APIClient;
 
  @POST("/login")
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<LoginResponse> loginPage(@Field("username")username,@Field("password")password);
}
```

**Repo Class:**

```
import 'APIClient.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

**class RepoClass{

 late APIClient mClient;
  RepoClass(){
    mClient= APIClient(Dio());
  }
 
  loginPage() async {
    var username = "black_coder";
    var password = "123456";
    var loginModel = await mClient.loginPage(username,password);
    //You can use your login model data as per your requirements.
  }**
```

but getting error at APIClient.dar saying

```
The name '_APIClient' isn't a type and can't be used in a redirected constructor.
Try redirecting to a different constructor.
```

Comment: so for start you have to create the ui screen for the login creds and then hit the post api using the username/email and password. then when you logged in successfully you need to store the token in local storage using the shared prefs. and then when you close the app and open again you just have to check if the token is not expired. if not then redirect to main screen if expired redirect to the login screen.

Comment: @SagarAcharya and how to post API can you share some code Example link. i am totally new for this

Answer (score 0):

> create SharedPreferences instance and save token as your preferable key

```
void signIn() async {

  var data = {'mobile': mobile, 'password': password};
  var res = await Network().signIn(data, '/login');
  var body = json.decode(res.body);
      
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['data']  ['token']));

 localStorage.setString('data', json.encode(body['data']));
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
         );
 } else if (res.statusCode != 200) {
 // mobileError = "These credentials do not match our records.";
}
}
```

Comment: Network is class where signin is a method for post reqest

Comment: use http package for network call, it's easy to handle

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about retrofit(network handler) & shared_preference(for save login state) at **Readme & Example** part

Retrofit: https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit

shared_preference: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

**Example of Retrofit: demo Github link:** https://github.com/HienNguyen102/flutter_retrofit

APIClient.dart

```
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
part 'APIClient.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://example.com")
abstract class APIClient {
  factory APIClient(Dio dio) = _APIClient;
 
  @POST("/login")
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<String> loginPage(@Field("email")emailId,@Field("password")password);
 
}
```

Don't forget to add these

```
dependencies:
  retrofit: ^3.0.1
  dio: ^4.0.4
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
  json_serializable: ^6.1.4

dev_dependencies:
  retrofit_generator: ^4.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
```

and run

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

so you can get this

```
part 'APIClient.g.dart';
```

*Next class*

RepoClass.dart

```
class RepoClass{
  APIClient mClient;
  RepoClass(){
    mClient= APIClient(Dio());
  }
 
  loginPage() async {
    var email = "abc@gmail.com";
    var password = "123456";
    var loginModel = await mClient.loginPage(email,password);
    //You can use your login model data as per your requirements.
  }
 
}
```

**Example of Share preference**

```
//Save string data
prefs.setString('email', "abc@gmail.com");
prefs.setString('password', "123456");
```

```
//Get string data
string email = prefs.getString('email');
string password = prefs.getString('password');
```

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: I updated my answer, Don't forget to add retrofit_generator & build_runner and run 'flutter pub run build_runner build'

Comment: in my post.api.g.dart file getting **The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'RepoClass'** this error

Comment: You can try response type of login function to Future<String> and run again, that retrofit's issues, you can read more about this at here if you don't wan't String as Response type, https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/316

Comment: i want json as a response type

Comment: @BlackCoder, I made a simple example at here, hope it will help you, it about use retrofit & flutter
https://github.com/HienNguyen102/flutter_retrofit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241374/discussion-between-hien-nguyen-and-blackcoder).